# Am I still obligated to wear hijab at school when the school forbids it?

Tags: practical-islam, women, hijab, school

As a Muslim girl I know that wearing a hijab (scarf for covering the hair) is compulsory and I do wear it. But wearing the hijab isn't permitted in the school where I study. They also don't allow other students to use things that would reflect their religion, like a Hindu student is not allowed to use a Bindi on his/her forehead. They say that this promotes equality among the students.

Now I am confused what to do. Is it acceptable not to wear hijab at school in this situation?

Comment: I agree with brother Ashiq's answer, but as an extreme measure you also should consider switching the school if the situation demands. But I hope that won't be necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sister, use of hijab is compulsory. Not just to cover your hair but also complete attire which doesn't reveal the shape of the body. Thus should be loose. Exempted are face and hands.. Consider reading

http://www.irfi.org/articles/articles_701_750/hijab_in_the_light_of_the_qur%27an.htm

To answer your question:

No school / any institution can forbid the use of hijab or forbid the practice of religious custom as per the government rule in India. It is best for your parents to speak to your school committee. I am sure Allah would help you finding a way so that all Muslim girls in your school shall enjoy wearing hijab.

May Allah shower his blessings upon you for having the neeyath of wearing hijab in your mind.

Comment: It is forbidden in France, all religious symbols, including Jesus cross are forbidden at school in France.

Comment: Sorry. It is the case in India @Kilise